# Does Traefik ratelimit apply on requests from other services?

Tags: docker, service, traefik, rate-limiting

If we setup Traefik for several services and add rate-limiting to one service, will this rate-limit then apply on requests between the services or only to requests external to the Traefik network?

I am running Traefik using Docker swarm.

Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The ratelimitis are configured per frontend (as per documentation)

So if your traefik endpoint is running on port 80 or 443 and you call a service on one of the configured traefik ports. Then the request will be counted in the rate limit.

But if your services communicate on internal ports, lets say,

- Service-A:19064
- Service-B:19065

And Service A calls Service B on port 19065, this will not be counted in the rate limit of traefik.